# I am expecting output as int, but getting float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to make a new Column named 'Years' from a data frame in python

my code is:

```
df['Years'] = df['Days']//365.
```

I want to get the output as int so I use '//' but why the output I get is in `float = 13.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Years'] = (df['Days']//365).astype('int32')
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the actual data type matter to you? `//` does flooring division, but the data type for your Series remains float.

If you really want integers, cast the series.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"days": [5303.0, 6604.1, 64202.2, 93.3]})
df["years"] = (df["days"] // 365).astype(int)
print(df.years)
```

```
0     14
1     18
2    175
3      0
Name: years, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the value that is present in the numerator. In this case the value in Days column is probably float.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).